# What is a true way to update ancestors components if a components tree has OnPush strategy set?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have tree of components, every component has `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, in that case ancestors components don't detect own local changes that they are making with, for example, observables or `setTimeout()`. I done this by adding `this.ref.markForCheck()` call where a component should be updated. But I guess it maybe not a good way to solve the problem.

So what is a true way to do this? Am I right that if I use third party component and it doesn't have `this.ref.markForCheck()` call it may not work?

Here is my lowest level component's code:

```
import {
  Component, HostBinding, ViewEncapsulation, AfterContentInit,
  Input, ViewChild, ElementRef, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

import { DestroyUnsubscribe } from 'services';

@Component({
  selector: 'jf-more',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  // changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  styleUrls: ['more.component.scss'],
  template: `
    <div class="more__open-button" *ngIf="!opened" (click)="onToggleClick()">
      <ng-content select="jf-more-open"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="more__text" [ngClass]="{'more__text_opened': opened}" #text>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="more__close-button" *ngIf="opened" (click)="onToggleClick()">
      <ng-content select="jf-more-close"></ng-content>
    </div>
  `,
})
@DestroyUnsubscribe()
export class MoreComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @Input() oneLineHeight = 16;
  @ViewChild('text') text: ElementRef;
  @HostBinding('class.more') mainClass = true;
  @HostBinding('class.more_initiated') initiated: boolean = false;
  @HostBinding('class.more_one-line') oneLine: boolean;
  opened: boolean;

  private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.makeLineCheck();
    this.subscriptions.push(
      Observable
        .fromEvent(window, 'resize')
        .debounceTime(500)
        .subscribe(() => this.makeLineCheck())
    );
  }

  onToggleClick() {
    this.opened = !this.opened;
    // this.ref.detectChanges();
    // this.ref.markForCheck();
  }

  private makeLineCheck() {
    this.initiated = false;
    this.opened = true;
    this.oneLine = false;
    // this.ref.detectChanges();
    this.ref.markForCheck();
    console.log('makeLineCheck', Object.assign({}, this));
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.oneLine = ($(this.text.nativeElement).innerHeight() <= this.oneLineHeight);
      this.initiated = true;
      this.opened = false;
      // this.ref.detectChanges();
      this.ref.markForCheck();
      console.log('setTimeout makeLineCheck', Object.assign({}, this));
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ApplicationRef.tick()` or `setTimeout(...)` invokes change detection for the root node, which then propagates down. If the components in between are set to `OnPush` and no inputs change, this won't cause change detection in these components though.

I would use shared services with observables to notify ancestors about changes for them to call `markForCheck()` for themselves.

Comment: Sad, this is actually what I thought about OnPush changes. Could you please clarify how to make it with services or better to give me an example? As you see I use observable but it does nothing.. Do services have a kind of hook so they invoke the check? And what could I do to make third party components work?

Comment: The ancestor would need to `this.mySharedService.someSubject.subscribe(x => this.cdRef.markForCheck());` When the descendant emits a value `this.mySharedService.someSubject.next(null);`, then the ancestor gets updated. Or alternatively if the ancestor uses the async pipe it should do the same `<div [myProp]="mySharedService.someSubject | async"`